# Finite groups with unbounded commutator width and no nontrivial central chief factor

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

The commutator width of a group is the smallest $n$ such that every product of commutators is a product of $n$ commutators.

My initial question was:

> Do there exist finite perfect groups with trivial center with unbounded commutator width?

It is known without the center-free assumption: the constructions I'm aware of crucially use that the center is large, namely producing for every $n$ a finite group $G$ with center $Z$ such that $|G/Z|^{2n}<|G|$ (so that the commutator width of $G$ is $>n$, using that the commutator map $G^2\to G$ factors through a map $(G/Z)^2\to G$).

Let me also mention the well-known fact that finite nonabelian simple groups have bounded commutator width ($=1$ by the somewhat recent solution to Ore's conjecture).

---

Edit Jan 8 '20:

Richard Lyons and Derek Holt showed in the comments the above question has a positive answer, observing that center-free groups are obtained by a simple trick: if $G$ is any finite group and $p$ is a prime not dividing $|G|$ then there exists a faithful $\mathbf{F}_pG$-module $V$ with trivial invariant submodule/quotient (just take $\mathbf{F}_pG$ modulo constants). Then if $G$ is perfect, then $G\ltimes V$ is a perfect group with at least as large commutator width, and in addition is center-free. (I hadn't thought of the trick of viewing $G$ as quotient of a center-free group!)

As suggested by Richard Lyons, let me therefore ask the following question:

> Do there exist finite groups with no central chief factor (that is, all of whose quotients have a trivial center) and unbounded commutator width?

Comment: The commutator width of $G$ is at least the commutator width of any quotient $G/N$. So there are examples where $G/N$ is perfect with arbitrarily large commutator width and $N$ is a faithful $F_p[G/N]$-module without trivial constituent, $p$ a prime not dividing the order of $G$. To avoid this you could require that there be no central chief factors.

Comment: @RichardLyons well, you seem to almost answer my question. It seems you're using the fact that every perfect finite group is quotient of a center-free one, or at least the in the known cases. In the cases in mind, the center $Z$ of $G$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group, and $G/Z$ is center-free, in case it helps.

Comment: But for any finite group $G$ and prime $p$ not dividing $|G|$, we can find a module $M$ over ${\mathbb F}_p$ on which $G$ acts faithfully and without fixed points. Take, for example, the quotient of the regular module (i.e. ${\mathbb F}_pG$) with the $1$-dimensional fixed point space factored out. Then $Z(M \rtimes G) = 1$ and $M \rtimes G$ is perfect if $G$ is.

Comment: @YCor Sorry I was not clear. The answer to your question is 'yes,' but you could change the question by replacing "trivial center" by "no central chief factors." Then the answer is not clear (to me anyway).

Comment: Or if the revised question is too hard, does there exist a finite group with no central chief factors in which not every element of the commutator subgroup is a commutator.

Comment: @DerekHolt I'll not change the question once more, but it's a good starting point!